# BodyBuilding Club database, which entities are most important

Tags: database

How I can come up with an effective BodyBuilding database, what entities are most important?

From which I should be able to come up with an ER diagram. I'm still a novice to databases, but I have read quite enough, most difficult I'm finding a problem with differentiating between a Gym database and BodyBuilding Club database.

Comment: This would entirely depend on the requirements and would probably require too much detail to be answered here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried listing everything you think relates to the database, then removing the ones you don't like, then grouping them in a way that makes sense to you or users of the database?

Certification types, access to bodybuilding books, bodybuilding trainers, ease of super sets, free weight ratios, ratings from heavy lifters, etc.

Try everything, make a list, narrow it down to the items needed for proper function and your business perspective (safety, legal, etc).

Comment: thanks a lot, let me see how it goes though iv found quite a number of Gym ER diagrams e.g. [link](https://12359753314275929142.googlegroups.com/attach/147e032bb1a3de0e/hcwll67r5.png?part=4&view=1&vt=ANaJVrGzS-2SIVYGRD32r4EdwLsB5NXbVbVAN8JzPS7p5cISqbcFRDz-cYqMoxnyN8zy9xoOR9NK035GrwPt9c7_HGjzwgEGG9Xn_v3cCmgnJj0_E1_kwSA) is it advisable to just add up some entities to a similar available ER diagram in this case a Gym so i can come up with a BodyBuilding club, because most of the entities seem to be compatible to both...thanks in advance